# SimpleSamlPhp Infinite login loop (once again)

Tags: php, saml, simplesamlphp

Yes, I've read all these threads with this same title!
After days of debugging, I think my problem are cookie mismatches.

I've used the basic code from https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp for SP test (which you can find everywhere here)

```
require_once('../../lib/_autoload.php');
$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');

if ($as->isAuthenticated ()) {

   $as->requireAuth();

}

$attributes = $as->getAttributes();
print_r($attributes);
```

I've tested several configurations targeting "store.type", "session.cookie.domain", and so on.

$as->isAuthenticated() get's never TRUE ...

For my question: I've found three cookies in browser context:

- Two from IdP named "SimpleSAML" and "SimpleSAMLAuthToken",
- One from SP named "SimpleSAMLSessionID".

Can somebody confirm if this correct or not?

Thanks!

Comment: would be great about hearing fixing this issue

Comment: I'd guess you're missing the `SameSite=None; Secure` flags from your `PHPSESSID` cookie. For some weird reason SimpleSAML doesn't set those default event though the SAML protocol cannot work without those flags.

Answer (score 2):

The infinite-loop issue with SimpleSAMLphp occurs if the PHP script uses a different session ID than SimpleSAML. Or if the PHP script uses an uncommon location to store sessions.

Edit the `simplesamlphp/config/config.php` and look for these settings. Adjust them to your PHP script's session configuration.

```
'session.phpsession.cookiename' => 'PHPSESSID',  // Default is SimpleSAML
'session.phpsession.savepath' => '/var/www/html/system/session',  // Default is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

So in my case, I was able to perform SSO login on Edge browser while it was not possible on Chrome (it stucked in login screen loop). The solution for me was to modify simplesamlphp config.php as follows:

```
/*
 * Set the SameSite attribute in the cookie.
 *
 * You can set this to the strings 'None', 'Lax', or 'Strict' to support
 * the RFC6265bis SameSite cookie attribute. If set to null, no SameSite
 * attribute will be sent.
 *
 * Example:
 *  'session.cookie.samesite' => 'None',
 */
// 'session.cookie.samesite' => \SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP::canSetSameSiteNone() ? 'None' : null,
'session.cookie.samesite' => strpos($userAgent, 'Chrome/') === false ? null : 'None',
```

Comment: Hey @Robert Ostrowicki - how has this solution been going? Do we have an understanding as to why we need to single out chrome in this scenario (other than observed behaviour)? It seems this issue is a common problem with SAML, with many possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to the enter character in the description attribute, it was difficult to find it, but I solved the problem. You can check that your own ldap attributes are entered correctly.